QGIS Stuck during boot-up 'QGIS READY'
QGIS freezing during software boot-up, gets stuck on QGIS READY screen and then crashes.
I've deleted default user profiles, .ini etc and uninstalled / reinstalle and still having no luck.
When inspecting the QGIS3.ini file I can see the following, which I assume could be the issue:
localized_data_paths=@Invalid()
Does anyone have suggestions are could you inspect your .ini for what the path should show?
My QGIS data files are stored on the C drive.
.ini file located here:
AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\QGIS3.ini

Solved.
Logged in on another user profile on my PC.
Copied all text from the QGIS3.ini file and pasted into the one associated with my profile.
It looks like the issue lies with QGIS trying to load a network drive which is not accessible.
